# how to take dynamic v-model in vuejs in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using v-form. and I am trying to take some input field in v-for loop dynamically. here is my code

```
<div class="row attribute-fields">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4" v-for="(singleAttribute,index) in attributes"
                                         :key="index">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="attribute_name">{{ singleAttribute.attribute_name }}</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attribute_name"
                                                   :placeholder="singleAttribute.placeholder" v-model="form.attribute[index]">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

and **this attribute is comming after on Change a selectLIst** ok thats give me the response. but i got a error in v-model. like this
[image]

and **in data property** in initialized my variable like this

```
form: new Form({
                id: '',
                category_id: '',
                subcategory_id: '',
                child_category_id:
                 attribute: [],
            })
```

**now i want to save all inputs value in attribute varibale using their index number**.like

```
form.attribute[1] = 'value';
```

PLease help me to solve this problem

Comment: `TypeError: Cann't read property '0' of undefined` indicates `this.form.attribute` is undefined. So it seems `Form` object doesn't have getter for `attribute`. Please check the guide for correct usage of `Form` class first.

Comment: ok i will upate you

Comment: thanks for your advice @sphinx